# How to add a new option box in WordPress Admin

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a new options box side of "Screen option" and "Help" and add some texts and fields.

[image]

Is it possible with WordPress actions?

Comment: Not easily possible - but can be done using PHP+JS - see [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25851/add-my-own-button-next-to-screen-options-and-help-in-the-admin) for instance.

Comment: I got it, thanks for your answer.